# how to make function validation alert if not selected

Tags: javascript

I already succeeded in making alert if the box is left empty or not filled in. All of my codes are working except for the GENDER and GRADE. For GENDER they have to tick to select. For Grade they have to select on the drop down menus.
Here are my codes.

```
    function validation()
{
    if(document.form1.first_name.value=="")
    {
       alert("Please enter your first name.");
       document.form1.first_name.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if(document.form1.last_name.value=="")
    {
       alert("Please enter your last name.");
       document.form1.last_name.focus();
       return false;
    }
    if(document.form1.gender.value=="")
    {
       alert("Please select your gender.");
       document.form1.gender.focus();
       return false;
    }
 if(document.form1.grade.value=="")
    {
       alert("Please select your grade.");
       document.form1.grade.focus();
       return false;
    }
```

First name, last name and others are working except for Grades and Gender. Please help me.

Comment: A checkbox doesn't have a value, it is checked, and a select box got a selected value, and a selected index. You should search about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select **dropdown validation** with **html**

```
<select required="required">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/ayv2edqc/)</kbd>

With **javascript**

```
<form onSubmit="return checkForm();">
<select id="grade" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />  
</form>

function checkForm(){
    var e=document.getElementById("grade").value;//alert(e);
    if(e===""){
        alert("nothing selected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/ayv2edqc/1/)</kbd>

**Checbox validation** with **html**

```
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" required="required" />
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/ayv2edqc/2/)</kbd>

With **javascript**

```
function check(){
var e=document.getElementById("remember").checked;
    //alert(e);
    if(!e){
    alert("not checked");
        return false;
    }
  }
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/ayv2edqc/3/)</kbd>

**Radio button** validation in **javascript**

```
<form onsubmit="return check();">
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="radio" />Male
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="radio" />Female
<input type="submit" />  
</form>
function check(){
var e=document.getElementById("remember").checked;
    //alert(e);
    if(!e){
    alert("not selected");
        return false;
    }
  }
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/ayv2edqc/4/)</kbd>

Comment: I used your code but instead of alert I used         document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = ("Please select a option part "); - my question is that how this text can be disappeared once user select all the options and submits them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(!document.getElementById('gender_male').checked && !document.getElementById('gender_female').checked)
```

and

```
if(document.form1.grade.selectedIndex == -1)
```

Use selectedIndex against -1 for select elements.
And use checked for radio buttons, on individual radio elements.

Answer (score -1):

put breakpoint in validation() function and see what is coming for 
document.form1.gender.value and document.form1.grade.value. 
Check for that result in if.

Comment: Don't you think you are not posting an answer. You are giving a suggestion , you may post it as a comment.

Comment: sorry my fault: The gender is radio button. One is selected by default i must be wrong it must not be compulsory. The only problem left is the Grade where there is a drop down menu namely Grade 7, Grade 8, grade 9, etc.. The default is the word "SELECT". What i wanted is the user will be alerted that he/she must select valid Grade in case of leaving it default

Comment: You got an answer in suggestion.